# Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior

Tags: algorithm, adsense, bots, googlebot

I am interesting in Google AdSense bot's algorithm and behavior with web site. I did not work with AdSense and i do not have account. So i need your help to understand:

1) Gbot from time to time downloads all pages from web site. Am i right?

2) Gbot do not understand dynamic content (loaded by ajax). So i must generate static content and return it within html page and this pages must show identical content for all users and for Gbot?

3) Because of (1) and (2) i cannot use only root path http://example.com with some "main" widget. I must generate unique pages for example http://example.com/thread?id=101 ?

4) Gbot downloads pages (1) for grabbing (indexing) keywords from them and then store (on it's servers) these information for example by key/value (where key is page path, value is tag cloud). Am i right?

5) When web site has been opened in browser by user. Integrated html AdSense's code loads some JavaScript. As i understand by "googling" this JavaScript do not index page, but makes call (with some parameter key==page_path) to Google's server and gets appropriate ad links. Then shows this ad links in it's frame. Is it right behavior? Maybe JavaScript makes some local indexing of page's content?

6) How Gbot and AdSense's JavaScript work with cookies? As i understand AdSense can use cookies for show appropriate ad links. If it is right, please give me some use cases;)

I know that "true" algorithm is known only by engineers from Google. But some of you had experience with AdSense and AdSense html/javascript. Please correct my vision of it;)

Thank you very much for any advice!!!

P.S. This question is very important for me. It is not some question for fun! So Please do not close it;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Yes if Googlebot can access the pages and if it knows about the pages through a link, XMLSitemaps, Google +1, etc.

2) Googlebot will now make AJAX / XHR requests to understand AJAX content (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/11/get-post-and-safely-surfacing-more-of.html).

Yes, you should show the same content to Googlebot as you would Users, otherwise this would be consider cloaking, which is against their guidelines.

3) This question isn't clear. But basically it's preferable to have the URL change because Google will then know how to index the content separately. If you're using AJAX then you might want to consider permalinks like you suggested, or you can use HTML5 popstate.

4) Yes Google will index the words on the page. I'm not certain they store it as a key/value pair. I'm not even sure if they're still using Big Table (http://labs.google.com/papers/bigtable.html) ... but it's likely they use Big Table or a similar system to store the inverted index.

5) The Adsense code is embedded Javascript ... for new webpages that Google hasn't seen before, it tries to deliver the most relevant ads based on the information it's found on the web about the site or possibly through anchor text of links pointing to that page. However, to get a more accurate understanding of the content of the page, Google will send an adsense specific bot to crawl your page ... sometimes you'll see it come very fast, even as soon as you load the page for the first time. It uses a different user agent than the traditional Googlebot ... you can find all the User Agents from Google here (http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1061943)

6) Google's crawlers don't accept cookies and won't pass back cookies to your server. It has to do with the massively distributed nature of Google crawlers that makes maintain cookies or sessions extremely difficult.